# Does the community user not "bump" inactive questions on beta sites?

Tags: discussion

This question: [Has materials modeling made any specific contribution to the success of perovskite solar cells, or has it only been experimental?](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/24/has-materials-modeling-made-any-specific-contribution-to-the-success-of-perovski)

Has not been edited or commented on for much more than a month. I thought by now it would be bumped, as described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334812/bumped-by-community-user.

I understand that the community user bumps only a maximum of 1 question per hour, but it seems that no questions here are getting bumped at all?

I did try to search "community user bump beta sites" to see if there was something on one of the Meta pages about this, but it seems it hasn't been asked before(?).

Here are some more examples that did not get bumped, but seem to satisfy all the criteria:

- [What kind of information can be extracted from alloy microstructure images converted to Fourier space?](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-kind-of-information-can-be-extracted-from-alloy-microstructure-images-conve)
- [What is the current status of active learning methods in atomistic machine learning?](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/51/what-is-the-current-status-of-active-learning-methods-in-atomistic-machine-learn)
- [Are there differences in accuracy and reliability between the frozen phonon method and Density Functional Perturbation Theory?](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/89/are-there-differences-in-accuracy-and-reliability-between-the-frozen-phonon-meth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because those questions do not have [**at least one answer** scoring zero, and no answers scoring above that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334814/8818397).

Edit: I see [What are some examples of active learning methods used in atomistic machine learning?](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/51/what-is-the-current-status-of-active-learning-methods-in-atomistic-machine-learn) now has an upvoted answer which is great.

Comment: A [question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4138/deterministic-termination-criteria-for-cbc) was bumped on OR just this morning by Community, it had 3 upvotes and had an unvoted answer at the time which matched the criteria.

Comment: I see. So it does happen on Beta sites. I've accepted your answer.